# How to re-export a framework and use it in another project in iOS? (Should I?)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two projects I'm working on in XCode. Project 2 depends on Project 1, and I want it to be able to use the same frameworks I have embedded in Project 1 (they're Carthage dependencies). I discovered the "Re-exported Framework Names" section in Build Settings, but I'm not at all clear on how I might use it.

- What should I put in that field? Just the name? (`PromiseKit`). Or the filename (`PromiseKit.framework`)? Or the full path?
- How do I then reference this framework in Project 2? Right now I'm getting a build error: `framework not found PromiseKit for architecture arm64` and I can't see any obvious way to add that framework link.

And a broader question: do I need to do this? I'm a relative newbie and working on the assumption that setting up separate Carthage dependencies for both projects means that there will be two separate compiled frameworks in my final binary, which would be a waste. But is XCode cleverer than I think and taking this into account?

Answer (score 1):

If the two projects are related, put them in the same Xcode workspace and then you can share the frameworks between the two.

If the projects are independent, put the frameworks into a separate folder, add them separately to both projects and when adding them to the projects, don't choose `Copy files if needed`.